# How is the reputation graph on my activity page generated?

Tags: support, profile-page, reputation-graph

There is a reputation graph on my activity page. The interval of abscissa on mine is several days. For someone else it is several months, and others years.

How is the graph generated?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on how long one has been a member on the site.

The graph will pick up a max of 4 years of reputation data if it exists. If a member has been around less than 4 years, 1 year of data will be used, then 4 months, then (if a user has been around under 4 months), all the available data will be used.

Comment: My own graph doesn't seem to be consistent with this answer. http://i.imgur.com/XUl2vHy.png

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - goes about a year back. The labels are not 100% accurate.

Comment: @Oded is this all server side? (calculation, I do see the values in client side)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - the calculation and range are server side.

Comment: I see, thanks. Any chance it can be "exposed" like the flair? I was considering starting such a feature request for a while, but if you say now it's too minor to be worth spending any time, I prefer not starting a lost battle.

Comment: Might be possible, in the future. There are still some consistency issues with it that I want to clear up first, @Sha

Comment: @Oded If there are 4 years on abscissa, are there 4 corresponding reputations on ordinate in theory? But I see there are 3 reputations on ordinate.

Comment: @xshsinap - not sure what you mean. Given that you have been a member here for less than 60 days, how would we show 4 years of data?

Comment: @Oded I mean why there are 4 scale on abscissa and ordinate scale only three.

Comment: @xshsinap - why shouldn't they be different? There is more space on the abscissa than the ordinate.

Comment: @Oded Yeah. I know what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: Why does this go up in steps? Why not show all available data all the time, like in the network profile graph?